# Spring Kafka and poll strategy on multiple partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Let's say I have a topic that has 4 partitions.
I'm consuming records with a spring kafka microservice using the @KafkaListener annotation.
This microservice is dockerized and I have two instances of it. Each instance is then plugged into two partitions.

I observe when I have lag to catch up to, that the instance stays on the partition it was on and lets the second partition accumulates lag. It will then only switch to this second partition when we stopped producing messages and the lag on the first partition is completely consumed.

The consuming order in my application is only partially important. What I mean by that is that I can process them in a different order but I can't let a message stay in a partition for too long.

The easy solution would simply be to have four docker instance and everything would be fine.

Is there some properties in spring-kafka that would allow us to change the polling strategy when the KafkaListener is plugged to multiple partition. The idea would be that it would round robin the polling on every partition is assigned to everytime it polls

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Where is the lag? Within kafka or you mean the lag=the msg processing time?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The lag is in kafka for my consumer because I didn't consume fast enough. But that's something I'm ok with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the consumer (listener container) `concurrency` on each instance to 2; that way you will have 4 consumers in 2 instances.

With spring boot, this is `spring.kafka.consumer.concurrency`. If you are creating your own factory, set the property directly.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! I hoped that we could do something else and avoid adding a layer of concurrency in the jvm since we already have one with docker but I guess it does not exist.
Again thanks :)